# What are the justification for Kants moral philosophy?

Tags: ethics

I have trouble understanding the justification Kant gives for his moral philosphy. 
My main problem is:

1. Why is practical reason the way humans can figure out the morality of an action?
2. Why is it our duty to act according to the categorical imperative?

I think that these are pretty big and broad questions but if anyone is able to give me an overview and/or point me in the right direction, thank you in advance!

Comment: i like the question, but do you have "trouble understanding" or have you not tried reading kant? not meaning to be rude, i just think that the question may be better answered if you explicitly said one or the other